# How to populate tinyMCE image upload popup fields after selecting image

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4, rich-text-editor, tinymce-plugins

First to mention I am stuck in **tinyMCE** version `4.0.20` (For some stability issue I am not able to update the version in my project)

I have initiated tinyMCE editor and all necessary plugins. I need to have a image upload feature here (actually embed the image as *data image*). In that purpose what I have done the code so far would be found in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1fn4bkug/2/)

Following is the `file_browser_callback` so far I have written.

```
function (field_name, url, type, window) {
   var input = document.createElement('input');
   input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
   input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');

   input.onchange = function () {
        var file = this.files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function () {
        var base64 = reader.result;

        var image = new Image();
        image.src = base64;
        image.alt = file.name;

        image.onload = function () {
          /*
           * just to work around I tried below to populate the fields.
           * but for putting dimesions, I dont know how to do that. I
           * think there should be some function or something in tinyMCE
           * for that purpose
           */
               window.document.getElementById(field_name).value = image.src;
               $('input.mce-last', window.document).val(image.alt);
          }

        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  };

  input.click();
}
```

I want to populate the popup fields with image **title**, **description** and **dimensions** from the image meta data. And you will notice there is a *checkbox* beside *dimensions* field *Contains proportion* that should work for *maintain proportion* from **tinyMCE**

I think the following image can help you understand.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, After wasting one another day I found the solution in [tinyMCE forum](http://archive.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=109028#p109028). What actually I needed to do is to trigger a change on the *url field* and this will auto fill in it's *width/height*.

```
var fieldElement = window.document.getElementById(field_name);

fieldElement.value = image.src;
fieldElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
```

As I mentioned earlier I am stuck in an older edition of **tinyMCE**, this workaround is for the version 4.2 and earlier. For later version **tinyMCE** comes with a better approach of this. You will find the proper documentation here about the changes [here](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/file-image-upload/)